# ¿Como instalar composer en una pc sin conexión a internet?

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Pregunto por acá si hay una posibilidad de instalar composer de laravel en una pc que no tenga acceso a internet, puesto que ya pasé la carpeta de xampp con el composer instalado allí en php, pasé los datos de appdata > roaming, y nada, pues me dicen que debo descargar una version full de composer la cual no he conseguido, pido si me pueden ayudar por alli y gracias de antemano...

Answer (score 1):

Composer es un gestor de dependencias a través de red (aunque se pueden preparas repositorios locales) por lo que si no tienes conexión no te va a ser muy útil.
Puedes directamente pasar la carpeta vendor del proyecto para usarla, pero no tendrás las dependencias actualizadas.

Si aun así lo quieres instalar lo tienes [AQUÍ](https://getcomposer.org/download/) [(INSTRUCCIONES)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-the-installer)

**Installation - Windows#**

**Using the Installer#**
This is the easiest way to get Composer set up on your machine.

Download and run Composer-Setup.exe. It will install the latest Composer version and set up your PATH so that you can call composer from any directory in your command line.

> Note: Close your current terminal. Test usage with a new terminal:
>   This is important since the PATH only gets loaded when the terminal
>   starts.

**Manual Installation#**
Change to a directory on your PATH and run the installer following the Download page instructions to download composer.phar.

Create a new composer.bat file alongside composer.phar:

```
C:\bin>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat
```

Add the directory to your PATH environment variable if it isn't already. For information on changing your PATH variable, please see this article and/or use Google.

Close your current terminal. Test usage with a new terminal:

```
C:\Users\username>composer -V
Composer version 1.0.0 2016-01-10 20:34:53
```

Comment: Agrega las instrucciones aquí